# Unity IAPurchase Revoke on Google Store

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am using a non-consumable product to switch off ads for good, after purchasing.
When users buy pro everything works fine. Ads are switched off, also autorenewal in google store works fine after the user reinstalls the app.

My problem starts when the user wants a refund. After all, will be processed by Google and the customer will get his money. I don't know how where to subscribe to my function to turn off the pro version again on the users' app.

I am using IAPManager:

```
public class IAPManager : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{
    public List<Product> ProductList = new List<Product>();

    public const string Pro = "pro";
    private const string _androidPostFix = "_android";

    [SerializeField] I18NText purchaseProBtnText;

    public IAPManager Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null) Instance = this;
        else Destroy(gameObject);

        Init();

        EventManager.PurchaseProduct += PurchaseProduct;
        EventManager.GetProLocalizedPriceString += GetProLocalPriceString;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        EventManager.PurchaseProduct -= PurchaseProduct;
        EventManager.GetProLocalizedPriceString -= GetProLocalPriceString;
    }

    public List<Product> AllProducts { get { return m_Controller.products.all.ToList(); } }

    private IStoreController m_Controller;
    private ITransactionHistoryExtensions m_TransactionHistoryExtensions;
    private IGooglePlayStoreExtensions m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions;

    private bool m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected;

    private bool m_PurchaseInProgress;

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION
    private CrossPlatformValidator validator;
#endif

    private string GetProLocalPriceString()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        foreach (Product product in ProductList)
        {
            if (product.metadata.localizedTitle == Pro)
            {
                return product.metadata.localizedPriceString;
            }
        }
        return null;
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
        foreach (Product product in ProductList)
        {
            if (product.metadata.localizedTitle == "Fake title for pro")
            {
                return product.metadata.localizedPriceString;
            }
        }
        return null;
#endif
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var module = StandardPurchasingModule.Instance();

        module.useFakeStoreUIMode = FakeStoreUIMode.StandardUser;

        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(module);

        // Set this to true to enable the Microsoft IAP simulator for local testing.
        builder.Configure<IMicrosoftConfiguration>().useMockBillingSystem = false;

        m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected = Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android && module.appStore == AppStore.GooglePlay;

#if AGGRESSIVE_INTERRUPT_RECOVERY_GOOGLEPLAY
        // For GooglePlay, if we have access to a backend server to deduplicate purchases, query purchase history
        // when attempting to recover from a network-interruption encountered during purchasing. Strongly recommend
        // deduplicating transactions across app reinstallations because this relies upon the on-device, deletable
        // TransactionLog database.
        builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().aggressivelyRecoverLostPurchases = true;
        // Use purchaseToken instead of orderId for all transactions to avoid non-unique transactionIDs for a
        // single purchase; two ProcessPurchase calls for one purchase, differing only by which field of the receipt
        // is used for the Product.transactionID. Automatically true if aggressivelyRecoverLostPurchases is enabled
        // and this API is not called at all.
        builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().UsePurchaseTokenForTransactionId(true);
#endif
        //builder.AddProduct(Pro, ProductType.NonConsumable);
        builder.AddProduct(Pro, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs
            {
                {Pro, GooglePlay.Name},
                //{Pro+_iosPostFix, AppleAppStore.Name}
            }
        );

#if INTERCEPT_PROMOTIONAL_PURCHASES
        // On iOS and tvOS we can intercept promotional purchases that come directly from the App Store.
        // On other platforms this will have no effect; OnPromotionalPurchase will never be called.
        builder.Configure<IAppleConfiguration>().SetApplePromotionalPurchaseInterceptorCallback(OnPromotionalPurchase);
        Debug.Log("Setting Apple promotional purchase interceptor callback");
#endif

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION
        string appIdentifier;
#if UNITY_5_6_OR_NEWER
        appIdentifier = Application.identifier;
#else
        appIdentifier = Application.bundleIdentifier;
#endif
        try
        {
            validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(), AppleTangle.Data(), appIdentifier);
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("Cross Platform Validator Not Implemented: " + exception);
        }
#endif

        // Now we're ready to initialize Unity IAP.
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        m_Controller = controller;
        m_TransactionHistoryExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<ITransactionHistoryExtensions>();
        m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IGooglePlayStoreExtensions>();

#if SUBSCRIPTION_MANAGER
        Dictionary<string, string> introductory_info_dict = m_AppleExtensions.GetIntroductoryPriceDictionary();
#endif
        // Sample code for expose product sku details for apple store
        //Dictionary<string, string> product_details = m_AppleExtensions.GetProductDetails();


        Debug.Log("Available items:");
        foreach (var item in controller.products.all)
        {
            if (item.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Join(" - ",
                    new[]
                    {
                        item.metadata.localizedTitle,
                        item.metadata.localizedDescription,
                        item.metadata.isoCurrencyCode,
                        item.metadata.localizedPrice.ToString(),
                        item.metadata.localizedPriceString,
                        item.transactionID,
                        item.receipt
                    }));
                ProductList.Add(item);
#if INTERCEPT_PROMOTIONAL_PURCHASES
                // Set all these products to be visible in the user's App Store according to Apple's Promotional IAP feature
                // https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/PromotingIn-AppPurchases/PromotingIn-AppPurchases.html
                m_AppleExtensions.SetStorePromotionVisibility(item, AppleStorePromotionVisibility.Show);
#endif

#if SUBSCRIPTION_MANAGER
                // this is the usage of SubscriptionManager class
                if (item.receipt != null) {
                    if (item.definition.type == ProductType.Subscription) {
                        if (checkIfProductIsAvailableForSubscriptionManager(item.receipt)) {
                            string intro_json = (introductory_info_dict == null || !introductory_info_dict.ContainsKey(item.definition.storeSpecificId)) ? null : introductory_info_dict[item.definition.storeSpecificId];
                            SubscriptionManager p = new SubscriptionManager(item, intro_json);
                            SubscriptionInfo info = p.getSubscriptionInfo();
                            Debug.Log("product id is: " + info.getProductId());
                            Debug.Log("purchase date is: " + info.getPurchaseDate());
                            Debug.Log("subscription next billing date is: " + info.getExpireDate());
                            Debug.Log("is subscribed? " + info.isSubscribed().ToString());
                            Debug.Log("is expired? " + info.isExpired().ToString());
                            Debug.Log("is cancelled? " + info.isCancelled());
                            Debug.Log("product is in free trial peroid? " + info.isFreeTrial());
                            Debug.Log("product is auto renewing? " + info.isAutoRenewing());
                            Debug.Log("subscription remaining valid time until next billing date is: " + info.getRemainingTime());
                            Debug.Log("is this product in introductory price period? " + info.isIntroductoryPricePeriod());
                            Debug.Log("the product introductory localized price is: " + info.getIntroductoryPrice());
                            Debug.Log("the product introductory price period is: " + info.getIntroductoryPricePeriod());
                            Debug.Log("the number of product introductory price period cycles is: " + info.getIntroductoryPricePeriodCycles());
                        } else {
                            Debug.Log("This product is not available for SubscriptionManager class, only products that are purchase by 1.19+ SDK can use this class.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Debug.Log("the product is not a subscription product");
                    }
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("the product should have a valid receipt");
                }
#endif
            }
        }
    }
    public void Restore()
    {
        m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions.RestoreTransactions(OnTransactionsRestored);
        Debug.Log("Restore method");
    }
    private void OnTransactionsRestored(bool success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Transactions restored." + success);
    }
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product item, PurchaseFailureReason r)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase failed: " + item.definition.id);
        Debug.Log(r);

        // Detailed debugging information
        Debug.Log("Store specific error code: " + m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastStoreSpecificPurchaseErrorCode());
        if (m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription() != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Purchase failure description message: " +
                      m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription().message);
        }

        m_PurchaseInProgress = false;
    }
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        Debug.Log("Billing failed to initialize!");
        switch (error)
        {
            case InitializationFailureReason.AppNotKnown:
                Debug.LogError("Is your App correctly uploaded on the relevant publisher console?");
                break;
            case InitializationFailureReason.PurchasingUnavailable:
                // Ask the user if billing is disabled in device settings.
                Debug.Log("Billing disabled!");
                break;
            case InitializationFailureReason.NoProductsAvailable:
                // Developer configuration error; check product metadata.
                Debug.Log("No products available for purchase!");
                break;
        }
    }

    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase OK: " + e.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
        Debug.Log("Receipt: " + e.purchasedProduct.receipt);

        m_PurchaseInProgress = false;

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION // Local validation is available for GooglePlay, and Apple stores
        if (m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.tvOS) {
            try {
                var result = validator.Validate(e.purchasedProduct.receipt);
                Debug.Log("Receipt is valid. Contents:");
                foreach (IPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in result) {
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.productID);
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.purchaseDate);
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.transactionID);

                    GooglePlayReceipt google = productReceipt as GooglePlayReceipt;
                    if (null != google) {
                        Debug.Log(google.purchaseState);
                        Debug.Log(google.purchaseToken);
                    }

                    AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt apple = productReceipt as AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt;
                    if (null != apple) {
                        Debug.Log(apple.originalTransactionIdentifier);
                        Debug.Log(apple.subscriptionExpirationDate);
                        Debug.Log(apple.cancellationDate);
                        Debug.Log(apple.quantity);
                    }

                    // For improved security, consider comparing the signed
                    // IPurchaseReceipt.productId, IPurchaseReceipt.transactionID, and other data
                    // embedded in the signed receipt objects to the data which the game is using
                    // to make this purchase.
                }
            }
            catch (IAPSecurityException ex)
            {
                Debug.Log("Invalid receipt, not unlocking content. " + ex);
                return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException exception)
            {
                Debug.Log("Cross Platform Validator Not Implemented: " + exception);
            }
        }
#endif
        // Unlock content from purchases here.
        if (e.purchasedProduct.definition.id == Pro)
        {
            //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("pro", 1);
            Debug.Log("PURCHASED PRODUCT!");
            //AdsManager.Instance.ProActive = true;
            AdsManager.Instance.HideAdsPro();
            //EventBroker.CallOnProBought();
        }


#if USE_PAYOUTS
        if (e.purchasedProduct.definition.payouts != null) {
            Debug.Log("Purchase complete, paying out based on defined payouts");
            foreach (var payout in e.purchasedProduct.definition.payouts) {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Granting {0} {1} {2} {3}", payout.quantity, payout.typeString, payout.subtype, payout.data));
            }
        }
#endif
#if DELAY_CONFIRMATION
        StartCoroutine(ConfirmPendingPurchaseAfterDelay(e.purchasedProduct));
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Pending;
#else
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
#endif
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method to start purchase product.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productID">Product ID from products on Google Dev Dashboard</param>
    public void PurchaseProduct(string productID)
    {
        Debug.Log("PurchaseProduct");
        if (m_PurchaseInProgress == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please wait, purchase in progress");
            return;
        }

        if (m_Controller == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Purchasing is not initialized");
            return;
        }

        if (m_Controller.products.WithID(productID) == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No product has id " + productID);
            return;
        }

        m_PurchaseInProgress = true;
        m_Controller.InitiatePurchase(m_Controller.products.WithID(productID), "developerPayload");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

I checked product.hasRecipt to get info if the product is bought.

So the receipt disappears after a successful revoke process in the google app store.
And every time the app is restarted this bool is sent to the app during IAP initialization.